"A is about 16 miles to the south of B". If we use arrow to represent the direction, is the direction of arrow from A to B, or from B to A?

"A is about 16 miles to the south of B".

If we use arrow to represent the direction, then which diagram is right? the first one (the arrow is from A to B) or second? ( the arrow is B to A)

According to "A is walking to B", then I think diagram 1 is right.
But based on common sense of direction, "A is about 16 miles to the south of B", then the location of B is known, and B is used to introduce the location A. So we should start from B, then base on the direction and distance to find A. So diagram 2 is more suitable.
Please tell me which diagram is right.

We say Maidstone is about 16 miles from London, not ...to London. Note that if you're actually in London, you can say It's about 16 miles to Maidstone [from here]. And obviously the distance from A to B is the same as from B to A, so if you're in Maidstone you can say It's about 16 miles to London. And wherever you are, you can say It's about 16 miles from Maidstone to London OR It's about 16 miles from London to Maidstone

Yes, your sentence is easier to understand. But if we use a map to introudce two locations, how to use "to". And this the original sentence from LangMan:  Knutsford is about 16 miles to the south of Manchester.

Your example Knutsford is about 16 miles to the south of Manchester is really a different construction, where preposition to introduces a direction, not a distance, origin, or destination (in that construction, to the is entirely optional - it's relatively formal / old-fashioned, and can simply be omitted).

Yes, "to" is used to introduce a direction which is usually  represented by an arrow. Then is Knutsford the start point and "Manchester" the end point? or oppsite?

Knutsford is about 16 miles to the south of Manchester simply describes a distance (and direction of the second location relative to the first). It doesn't particularly imply traveling. You usually identify the better-known location first in such constructions, because the whole point is to tell someone where the second location is. But it means exactly the same if phrased as Manchester is about 16 miles [to the] north of Knutsford.

Think your answers.

It's usual to show north at the top, so I would expect to see A in the lower box!

Yes, that was a mistake. I have corrected it.  When I think see this sentence " "A is about 16 miles to the south of B". I will imagine: A --16miles--> (the south of B) [corresponding to the second picture in the question]. Do you think my idea is right?

Your question is not clear.  The relative location of A with respect to B does not require any arrow.  The arrow implies movement between the locations, not location per se.

What @TimR said. Except in many cases we put arrows at BOTH ends of the "distance" line to make clear between exactly which two points that distance applies (this is more common in construction plans and parts diagrams than in maps, obviously).

Neither diagram is "right" because the sentence "A is 16km to the South of B" doesn't give a direction, it only gives a relative location.
In the sentence "A is 16km to the South of B" there is no sense of motion, and no implied movement from one place to the other.
I would represent this by a double-headed arrow ↕ or something similar.
You might say that both your diagrams are correct, as the distance from A to B is the same as the distance from B to A. So you could use either arrow.
The subject of the sentence "A is 16 miles to the south of B" is the place "A".  And grammatical subjects normally indicate the topic of discussion.  Hence, normally, you would use that sentence to give information about A.  You assume that the location of B is known, and you are giving information about the location of A.
If I assume you know the location of "London" and I want to tell you about the location of "Lingfield" (a village that I assume you don't know).  I would phrase my sentence "Lingfield is 25 miles south of London" rather than the logically equivalent "London is 25 miles north of Lingfield".  I chose that order because I am talking about Lingfield, so I make that the subject.

What I really want to know is how native speaker will imagine in the head when he or she sees the sentence: "A is  to the south of B".  When reading this sentence, I will think of A first which is a location, then "to" which means some distance. At last, "the south of B". If I don't know the location A but know the location B, I will guess the position of A is from the south of B, then go to some distance to A, which is equivalent to diagram B in my question

@Jesse  The native speaker is not imagining a person.  There is no deixis involved here.

The subject of the sentence "A is 16 miles to the south of B" is the place "A".  And grammatical subjects normally indicate the topic of discussion.  Hence, normally, you would use that sentence to give information about A.  You assume that the location of B is known, and you are giving information about the location of A.
